# How to set default value of a parameter of a function when it is 'undefined' or 'null' or ''(empty string)?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, null, undefined

colorX is my parameter from some function.

```
colorX = typeof colorX !== ('undefined' || 'null' || '') ? colorX : 'abc';
```

Here for 'undefined' I'm getting abc as value. But when I pass null or 'null' or empty string as parameter input. I'm getting error.

Also what is the difference between null and 'null'?

Comment: `'null'` is a string while `null` is actually null

Comment: `typeof … !== ('undefined' || 'null' || '')` doesn't make any sense. It's equivalent to `typeof … !== 'undefined'` for all purposes.

Comment: As @Bergi said, the OR operator does not function as so, you would have to explicitly state all comparisons: `x == 'undefined' || x == ''`. You can shorten this with a `.includes`: `let ok = ['undefined', 'string']; console.log(ok.includes(typeof colorX))`.

Answer (score 2):

## Explanation

### `null` vs `'null'`

When using `typeof`, it expects a string version of the type, such as `'undefined'`, `'function'`, `'bigint'`, and so on. However, specifically for the `null` type it functions as an object:

```js
console.log(typeof null); // expected output: object
console.log(typeof 'strExample'); // expected output: string

// We can return a boolean by doing so:

let variable = 10;
console.log(typeof variable === 'string'); // expected output: false
```

The explanation as to why can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#typeof_null):

> In the first implementation of JavaScript, JavaScript values were represented as a type tag and a value. The type tag for objects was `0`. `null` was represented as the NULL pointer (`0x00` in most platforms). Consequently, `null` had 0 as type tag, hence the `typeof` return value `"object"`. ([reference](https://www.2ality.com/2013/10/typeof-null.html))
>
> A fix was proposed for ECMAScript (via an opt-in), but [was rejected](https://web.archive.org/web/20160331031419/http://wiki.ecmascript.org:80/doku.php?id=harmony:typeof_null).
> It would have resulted in `typeof null === 'null'`.

In any other scenario, `'null'`, `'undefined'`, and `'string'` would be identified as strings since they are surrounded in `''`'s, where this is what @reyno was referring to.

See all accepting values for `typeof` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#description).

#### Checking for null

```js
// null will be identified as an "object" type; checking
// null with typeof is redundant as {} can be the same as null.

console.log(typeof null); // expected output: object
console.log(typeof {}); // expected output: object

// so we can just do:

let colorX = null;
console.log(colorX === null); // expected output: true
```

### Resulting Code

Since falsy values can be any of these:

> Besides `false`, possible falsy expressions are: `null`, `NaN`, `0`, the empty string (`""`), and `undefined`.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator#description)

We can simply do:

```js
colorX = colorX || 'abc';
```

As @ivar claims.

Comment: I wanna check for all falsy values except for 0. In 1 case 0 must be accepted as a parameter. Is there a way to make an exception for 0?

Comment: I see you already solved the problem via Corrl's answer and comments; the entire answer would just be `colorX = colorX || colorX === 0 ? colorX : 'abc';`

Answer (score 1):

Using the ternary operator you could simplyfy this to

```js
colorX = colorX ? colorX : 'abc';
```

The Conditional (ternary) operator syntax is

```js
condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse
```

and according to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) docs

> ...null, NaN, 0, the empty string (""), and undefined. If condition is any of these, the result of the conditional expression will be the result of executing the expression exprIfFalse.

But alternatively and even shorter (in case you are checking for all 'falsy' values) you might as well use the [logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)

```js
colorX = colorX || 'abc';
```

Since you say you want to check for all falsy values except for 0 you can combine both

```js
let v = 0

v = v || v === 0 ? v : 'value'

console.log(v) // 0
```

Notice that

```js
null, undefined, 0
```

with quotes simply become strings containing the characters without "functional meaning"

Comment: If you're going to check for all falsy values (and not just `null`/`undefined`/empty string), you might as well simply use the logical OR. `colorX = colorX || 'abc'`

Comment: I wanna check for all falsy values except for 0. In 1 case 0 must be accepted as a parameter. Is there a way to make an exception for 0?

Comment: @SrinivasNaik I updated the answer

Comment: Thanks @Corrl. I tried this ```colorX = colorX || 0```. No more errors. But I feel your approach ```let v = 0

v = v || v === 0 ? v : 'value'

console.log(v) // 0``` is better.

Comment: @SrinivasNaik just 'colorX = colorX || 0' will give you always 0 if colorX is falsy, this is your 'fallback value' then. 'colorX = colorX || colorX === 0 ? colorX : 'fallback'' will give you 0 if it's 0 - if it's any other falsy value like undefined or null you get the 'fallback value'

Comment: Yup. If I want to set any other fallback value and accept 0 also as input ```colorX = colorX || colorX === 0 ? colorX : 'fallback'``` will be an option. But in this case I want to set the default as zero so ```colorX = colorX || 0``` works for me. Thank you guys for helping me with this :)